# How do I reach to AWS Route 53 API endpoint in a private VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-route53

I'm using Terraform to create DNS records automatically while after creating a K8s Ingress object. But Terraform AWS provider fails to connect to Route 53.
I'm ruining the TF scripts on an EC2 instance located in a private subnet. I use VPC endpoints to connect to AWS APIs. But there's no Route 53 private api endpoint in AWS.
How do I use the Route 53 API endpoint while being in a private subnet?

Comment: You could need to use a NAT Gateway to access the Internet from the private EC2 instance.

Comment: Can't be done without a NAT Gateway since there isn't a VPC Interface for Rourte53 at this time. In general, running Terraform in a private subnet without Internet access is going to be full of problems like this.